# Processing SQL response from multi-dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

Each row of SQL request returns multi-dimentional array with only 1 element "active" now when I do this it outputs even part of array that is "0" as well

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sql_response); $i++) {
    foreach ($sql_response[$i] as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "active"){
            echo "<br>".$key." - ".$value;
        };
    };
};
```

If I use === in IF it works, why it does not work with == it seems like i never had this problem with single denominational arrays.

Comment: I nelieve you mean "Each row of sql RESPONSE"

Comment: Which programming language is this? It sure doesn't look like SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If `$sql_response` contains something like:

```
array(
    0 => "value",
    "active" => "value"
)
```

then the `foreach` statement will go through both elements, first assigning `0` to `$key`, then assigning `"active"` to key.

`$key == "active"` will return `true` when `$key` is `0`, because:

- it compares `0 == "active"`
- which casts `"active"` to integer so it can be compared with `0`
- which results in `0 == 0`
- which is `true`

If you're using the `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*` functions to obtain `$sql_response`, then to prevent adding the numeric keys to the result array, use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead of their `*_fetch_array` counterparts.

Comment: nice... I never know that it would cast a string of letters to a number in this case... this is good to learn.